# Can we perform any machine learning modelling by using Neural Network?

Tags: regression, neural-networks, logistic, classification, softmax

I am trying to understand the powerful modelling capacity of neural network. As we know

1. Logistic regression can be performed by using neural network with single output node, no hidden layer and logistic activation function. For example: In logistic regression: suppose, $x_1=1, x_2=2,x_3=3, ω_1=0.01, ω_2=0.02, ω_3=0.03,ω_0=0.05⇒z=0.19,  p=0.5474>0.5$⇒predicted class=1. In a neural network, $z=ω^⊤ x=ω_0+ω_1 x_1+ω_2 x_2+ω_3 x_3,  f(z)=1/(1+exp(−z))$. Suppose, $x_1=1, x_2=2,x_3=3, ω_1=0.01, ω_2=0.02, ω_3=0.03,ω_0=0.05⇒z=0.19,p=0.5474>0.5$⇒predicted class=1.
2. SoftMax regression can be performed by using neural network with multiple output nodes and SoftMax activation function.
3. Linear regression can be performed by using neural network with identity function as an activation function.

Likewise various other learning model can be performed by a neural network. So, neural network is acting as an approximator of any of machine learning model. Can we have a descriptive proof or any reference of the above claim?

Comment: Do you mean the [universal approximation theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)?

Comment: Yes, I want to see the general proof followed by examples. Thanks.

Comment: The Wikipedia article gives a bunch of references. I suspect some of them prove the theorem.